# How to deserialize a small amount of JSON in WP7 using DataContractJsonSerializer

Tags: json, web-services, windows-phone-7, deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize the JSON results from a web request.

Here is my code.

```
    void myButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            Uri uri = new Uri("http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Specialty/ESRI_StateCityHighway_USA/MapServer/1/query?text=&geometry=&geometryType=esriGeometryPoint&inSR=&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&relationParam=&objectIds=&where=POP1999%3E15000000&time=&returnCountOnly=true&returnIdsOnly=false&returnGeometry=false&maxAllowableOffset=&outSR=&outFields=STATE_NAME%2CMALES%2CFEMALES%2CPOP1999&f=json");
            webClient.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(webClient_OpenReadCompleted);
            webClient.OpenReadAsync(uri); 
            //RESULT {"count":4}

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); 
        }
    }

    void webClient_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataContractJsonSerializer ser = null;
        try
        {
            //countertext.Text =  DESERIALIZE COUNT HERE
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); 
        }

    }

    public class Counter
    {
        public int count { get; set; }
    }
}
```

It seems like it should be pretty simple, but I cannot figure it out.

I want to use this code during a background agent and I can't use the ArcGIS runtime for windows Phone API during an Background agent because it is a third party API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should deserialize without a problem:

```
var ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Counter));
Counter r = (Counter) ser.ReadObject(e.Result);

System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(r.count);  // 4
```